# CakePHP 3 table relations

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the following tables: cars, car_types and car_methods. My issues with this are the relations. The car has one type and one method.

My goal is to show cars and his attachment "car type" and "car_method".

**Cars table:**

```
id - type_id - method_id
```

**Car_types table:**

```
id - type
```

**Car_methods table:**

```
id - method
```

How can I set this up inside my Model tables so that I can do inside my controller something like:

```
$this->Cars->CarTypes->find('all');
```

I tried as follow but it will give a No associated error:

**Cars model:**

```
class CarsTable extends Table {
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('cars');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasOne('CarTypes', [
        'className' => 'Cars.CarTypes',
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
        'propertyName' => 'type'
    ]);

    $this->hasOne('CarMethods', [
        'className' => 'Cars.CarMethods',
        'foreignKey' => 'method_id',
        'propertyName' => 'method'
    ]);
}
}
```

**CarTypes model:**

```
class CarTypesTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('car_types');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('Cars', [
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
    ]);
}
}
```

**CarMethots model:**

```
class CarMethodsTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('car_method');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('Cars', [
        'foreignKey' => 'method_id'
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to the documentation? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: Yes i've tries the documentation, but I do not quite understand it. I've added the code for you.

Comment: It's has many cars for types and methods. You point to the table itself for types and methods as you do right now. Do the tutorials in the book or some generic SQL tutorial on how to associated date. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two last relations are wrong, here is the good ones

## CarTypes model:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->hasMany('Cars', [  //A CarType hasMany Cars
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id'
    ]);
}
```

## CarMethods model:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->hasMany('Cars', [  //A CarMethod hasMany Cars
        'foreignKey' => 'method_id'
    ]);
}
```

## Controller action

And for your query, add this two relations to the contain option :

```
//Get all cars with type and method
$this->Cars->find('all',
     [
        'contain' => ['CarTypes', 'CarMethods'] 
     ]
);
```

Comment: I've updated the models inside my question with your example but I still got a (unable to export object: Cars is not associated with CarTypes and CarMethods) }.

Comment: I have solved it. The namespaces of my models where not linked to my plugin. Sometime a problem is so simple. :) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

> The belongsTo association is a natural complement to the hasOne and hasMany associations: it allows us to see the data from the other direction.
>
> belongsTo: the current model contains the foreign key.

If you have foreign key in your table, then that table will belong to the associated table. So, in your case :

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
     $this->belongsTo('CarTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
        'joinType' => 'LEFT'
     ]);

     $this->belongsTo('CarMethods', [
         'foreignKey' => 'method_id',
         'joinType' => 'LEFT'
     ]);
}
```

After this you can use `$this->Cars->CarTypes->find('all');`